# How to show values of input type="date" when user focus out from input if some value entered

Tags: html, css

I tried to solve the first part of the question using `color: white` which makes it hide to eyes.

As you can see in first input when it is focused `color` changes to `lightblue` , when some value entered(can be space too) `color` changes to `blue`. If no value is entered `color` changes back to original .

Well the first and last part of `color` changes occurs in 2nd input(`type="date"`) too , i.e, when focus changes to `lightblue` , onfocus out changes back to original color.

But I want to have same functionality in 2nd too , i.e, if some value(`date`) is entered `label` `color` changes to `blue` and `input` `color` remains `black`. Is this possible in CSS like as done in first `input`

```css
input:focus~label {
  color: lightblue;
}

input:not(input[type="date"]):not(:placeholder-shown)~label {
  color: blue;
}

input[type="date"] {
  color: white;
}

input[type="date"]:focus {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" placeholder=" " required>
  <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
</div>

<br><br><br>

<div>
  <input type="date" name="birth" id="birth" placeholder=" " required>
  <label for="birth" class="birthLabel">Birthday</label>
</div>
```

**Edit :** As the desired behavior is achieved by using `:valid` but it is only possible when `input` has `required` or some pattern to match. So this can't be case always then is there any other workaround when these (`required`) are not present on `input`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check if valid

```
input[type="date"]:valid~label {
  color: blue;
}
```

```css
input:focus~label {
  color: lightblue;
}

input:not(input[type="date"]):not(:placeholder-shown)~label {
  color: blue;
}

input[type="date"] {
  color: white;
}

input[type="date"]:focus {
  color: black;
}

input[type="date"]:valid~label {
  color: blue;
}

input[type="date"]:valid {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" placeholder=" " required>
  <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
</div>

<br><br><br>

<div>
  <input type="date" name="birth" id="birth" placeholder=" " required>
  <label for="birth" class="birthLabel">Birthday</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Now that way `color` is changed from the start only and also `input` value `color` don't change to black when some value is entered

Comment: @Rana check update, is there what you want?

Comment: yes just that only add `input[type="date"]:valid {color: black;}` . This is what I wanted to do   . Thanks a lot(+1)

Comment: Is there any workaround to that too , when `required` is not used in `input` `type="date"`